# Hibernate Envers with JBoss, Spring and Maven - Doesn't write audit record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I am trying to do a Hibernate Envers implementation in conjuction with Spring, JBoss and Maven.

I have the following:

- spring.version: 3.1.0.RELEASE
- hibernate.version: 3.5.0-Final
- log4j.version: 1.2.14
- jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
- mysql DB

In the pom.xml I have added the required hibernate-envers:

```
    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>    
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>    
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my Hibernate persistance class, I am importing the following

```
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
```

So it looks like

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Audited 
@Table(name = "COM_TEST")
public class MyTest extends AbstractReferenceDataObject { ...
```

I have ensured that there is a COM_TEST_AUD db table with the relevant DB columns as well as a REVINFO db table.

When I run my code, it uses the existing hibernate implementation to update a record in COM_TEST. But nothing is written to the COM_TEST_AUD or REVINFO db tables.

I have the following properties in my persistence.xml

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="./lucene/indexes"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.merge_factor" value="10"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.batch.max_buffered_docs" value="10"/>
    </properties>
```

I have tried just about everything I can think of. I can see when I start JBoss, it does say how it needs and fines the COM_TEST_AUD and REVINFO, so looks like that works.

I just can't work out why it wont write to the DB. There is nothing written to the log file and I have the logging set to:

```
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
```

I have noticed that in the JBoss modules directory below it uses hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\hibernate\envers\main
```

I have changed my project pom.xml to be 4.0.1.Final instead of 3.5.0-Final, but it didn't make a difference

Can someone please help?

Comment: The first thing to check is the transaction setup. What kind of transactions do you use? Are the Envers listeners called at all when e.g. persisting an entity?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Hibernate 3.x you need to configure the appropriate EventListeners in `persistence.xml`, as mentioned in the [Quickstart](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html/quickstart.html) section of the Envers docs:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert"
         value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update"
         value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete"
         value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update"
         value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove"
         value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate"
         value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
```

Note: You didn't state that you're using Hibernate via JPA, but since you mention a `persistence.xml`, you seem to be using JPA. If that's now the case, the configuration is a bit different, as you can see in the documentation.

If you're using Hibernate 4.x, this configuration is [not needed](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e3889)